To Show $ \mu(n)\mu(n+1)\mu(n+2)\mu(n+3) = 0 $
To show that
$ \mu(n)\mu(n+1)\mu(n+2)\mu(n+3) = 0 $
where, $ \mu $ is Mobius $\mu$ function
Write $n = (p_1)^{a_1}(p_2)^{a_2}(p_3)^{a_3}...(p_k)^{a_k}$
Case 1 : If $n$ is even. Then say $p_1 = 2$. Write $n$ as $$n=2^{a_1}(p_2)^{a_2}(p_3)^{a_3}...(p_k)^{a_k}$$
$$ a_1 \geq 1 $$
If $a_1 \geq 2$ then we are done as $\mu(n)=0$. Otherwise if $a_1=1$. Then write  $$n=2(p_2)^{a_2}(p_3)^{a_3}...(p_k)^{a_k}$$. Since all primes (except 2) in list are odd, so their product will also be odd.
$$n=2.(Odd number)$$
So $n+2$ = $ 2(O) + 2  $ = $ 2 (O + 1) = 2.2. (M) $, where O is some odd number and M is some number. So $\mu (n+2)= 0 $.
Case when n is even is similar.
My doubt is that book proves this by using division algorithm. so i am not sure my proof works.
Thanks

One out of every four consecutive numbers is divisible by $4$.

@lulu i think that is what i have shown. havenot I ?

But you go the long way round for it.  Let $r$ be the remainder on dividing $n$ by $4$, so $r\in {0,1,2,3}$.  If $n=4k+0$ we are done.  If $n=4k+1$, then $n+3=4(k+1)$.  If $n=4k+2$ then $n+2=4(k+1)$, if $n=4k+3$ then $n+1=4(k+1)$ and we are done.   The prime factorization of $n$ is not needed.

Or, if you prefer, just use the pigeonhole principle.  There are only three natural numbers between any two consecutive multiples of $4$, so you can't fit in your $4$ numbers.

@lulu Thanks but i have not studied pigeonhole principle yet. But my proof is acceptable if i write this in exam ??

Well...you say "Case when $n$ is even is similar." but you just did the even case, so you meant to write "odd".  And I wouldn't just dismiss that entire case so cavalierly.  I'd write it out.  But, really, bringing up the prime factorization is just unnecessary...you barely use it.  In the even case, with $n=2k$.  You could write "$k$ is even or odd.  If it is even, we are done since $k=2m\implies n=4n$.  If $k$ is odd we are done since $k=2m+1\implies  n=4m+2\implies n+2=4(m+1)$. "  and so on.

@lulu if n is odd then n+1 and n+3 are even

Yes, and then you need to show that one of $n+1, n+3$ is divisible by $4$.

@SophieClad Do note that "Is my proof acceptable if I write this on an exam?" is very different from "Is this proof correct?".  The former isn't really answerable without specifying the level of rigor expected on the exam, and the latter (which is what you seem to be asking) is too broad to be appropriate for this forum.
